# Preg_match for extracting particular string containing rows in PHP file reading

Tags: php

The below code is used for reading the csv file in php which has different sections separated using the tab counts. I ought to read the below text block with tab count 8 and extract the rows containing the `NO_COMMERCIAL_USE` string

```
<?php
// sample code
for ($j = 0; $j < count($file); $j++) {//for loop to read file
    $count_tab = substr_count($file[$j], ",");
    if ($count_tab === 8){ //open if for count tab
        $P = explode(",", $file[$j]);

        if($P[0]!='# BSC_NUM'){

            if (preg_match("0;NO_COMMERCIAL_USE", array_values($P)[8])){


                print_r($file[$j]);       // i am not able to get the desired output

            }//if loop preg
        } // exclude line
    } // count tab
?>
```

The file to be read contains the below text.I need to extract the lines containing 
"0; NO_COMMERCIAL_USE". I am new to file reading in PHP.

```
#BSC_NUM, BTS_INDEX, BTS_NAME, BTS_HW_GENERATION, BTS_FAMILY, ANTENNA_DIVERSITY, QMUX_ADDRESS, MUX_RULE, COMMERCIAL_USE; 
1,1,BEE206RUOI9KAJ_Wida_NOR,,,,1081,statisticMux64,1; 
1,2,BEE165RNBO9MJG_Chinchwan_IMP,,,,1335,statisticMux64,1; 
1,3,BEE081RBSI2KAJ_Hanumanpimpri_NOR,,,,1003,statisticMux64,1; 
1,4,BEE187RBSI3KAJ_SarniSangvi_NOR,,,,1097,statisticMux64,0;NO_COMMERCIAL_USE 
1,5,BEE186RBSI3KAJ_Gotegaon_NOR,,,,1099,statisticMux64,1; 
1,68,BEE012RBSI3ABJ_Ghatnandur,,,,11345,statisticMux64,0;NO_COMMERCIAL_USE 
1,69,BEE073RBSI2ABJ_Dharmapuri_NOR,,,,1347,statisticMux64,1; 
1,70,BEE808RINO8KAJ_AG_Lahuri,,,,1032,statisticMux64,1; 
17,2,SAT197RBSI9STR_MHASVE_NOR,,,,1020,statisticMux64,1; 
17,3,SAT157RBSI9PSG_DISKAL_NOR,,,,1333,statisticMux64,1; 
17,11,SAT223RBSI9STR_SASPADE_NOR_LOR,,,,1068,statisticMux64,1; 
17,12,SAT065RBSI3KOG_TARGAON_NOR,,,,1006,statisticMux64,1; 
17,13,SAT096RNBM3STR_EMERSON-ATIT_NOR,,,,1027,statisticMux64,0;NO_COMMERCIAL_USE 
17,14,SAT255UTVI9KOG_KOREGAON-GPT,,,,1124,statisticMux64,1; 

The output should be containing "0;NO_COMMERCIAL_USE"
1,4,BEE187RBSI3KAJ_SarniSangvi_NOR,,,,1097,statisticMux64,0;NO_COMMERCIAL_USE 
1,68,BEE012RBSI3ABJ_Ghatnandur,,,,11345,statisticMux64,0;NO_COMMERCIAL_USE
17,13,SAT096RNBM3STR_EMERSON-ATIT_NOR,,,,1027,statisticMux64,0;NO_COMMERCIAL_USE
```

Comment: You're missing the word `if` before `($count_tab == 8)`. Is that in the real code or a copying error?

Comment: Sorry...its a copying error!!

Comment: You're also missing the closing `}` for `for`. BTW, I strongly recommend you learn to use `foreach`, it makes the code simpler and easier to read.

Comment: There's no need to use `array_values()`.

Comment: You're not using `preg_match` correctly, you should be getting an error from that.

Comment: But there's no need to use `preg_match` at all. It's not a pattern, it's just an exact string.

Comment: @Barmar I just clipped a part of my code section. When I print the array_values($P)[8] it gives me the last column entries. But when I use preg_match it doesnt print anything..

Comment: @Barmar if I do a direct match like if($P[8] == '0;NO_COMMERCIAL_USE') it is not giving any result.

Comment: You're missing the delimiters around the regexp.

Comment: How are you reading the file? Do you remove the newlines before splitting?

Comment: @Barmar I have figured it out..... You were right there is no need of preg_match. I just used another explode inside the $P wrt  ";" semicolon . Which fetched me arrays in which the second element has the 1; & "NO_COMMERCIAL_USE" . Then the thing that i was missing was that i didnt use trim which was giving me unmatched strings